# Pass binding that is dependent on another binding

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm rather new to `SwiftUI`, so please bear with in case I mix up the nomenclature.

I have an `Int` `@State` property that is used in a `TabView` to hold the current index. Then I have a function that takes a `Binding<Bool>` to display another view.

What I basically want to do is pass a condition into the function whenever my `Int` state reaches a given value.

Sample code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FooTabView: View {
    @State private var selected = 0
    @State private var shouldShow: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selected) {
            Text("Hello")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Foo")
                }.tag(0)
            Text("World")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Bar")
                }.tag(1)
        }.anotherFunctionReturningAView(show: shouldShow)
    }
}
```

Lets say `shouldShow` should only be true, when `selected` is equal to `1`. How would I do that?

Comment: `onChange(of: selected) { if $0 == 1 { shouldShow = true } }`... in other words, change the property however you want, and pass a binding to the property as usual

Comment: @NewDev Thanks, that actually works as well! Man, SwiftUI has so many extensions, it's hard to keep up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your goal but you can try:

```
.anotherFunctionReturningAView(show: .constant(selected == 1))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent the "other view", e.g. if you used it with `.sheet(isPresented: .constant(selected == 1)) { }`, from changing the bound value, kinda defeating the purpose of a binding?

Comment: @NewDev Yes, it does. If you try it, the sheet will re-open on dismissal. As your binding now _depends on another value_, you have to update _the other_ value to close the sheet. But this is what was requested.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Proxy Binding, making it depend on your @State variable like that

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selected = 0
    @State private var shouldShow: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selected) {
            Text("Hello")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Foo")
                }.tag(0)
            Text("World")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Bar")
                }.tag(1)
        }.alert(isPresented: Binding<Bool>(
            get: {
                selected == 1 // << Here comes your condition
            }, set: {
                shouldShow = $0
            })
        , content: {
            Alert(title: Text("Test"))
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works, but @pawello2222's answer is a bit shorter.

Comment: No problem, agree, his solution is much simpler and does not require any additonal State variable.